# adding numbers in base n

Tags: algorithm, integer, addition

I came across this question and couldn't figure out how to approach it. Can someone please help me out? The question is-

- Add numbers in base n (not any of the popular ones like 10, 16, 8 or 2 - I hear that Charles Simonyi, the inventor of Hungarian Notation, favors -2 when asking this question).

I just need the idea.

Comment: i have no idea why you got downvoted but this has everything you need: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify a language, but you could just convert the base n number into a standard integer and add it.

Suppose base N number = '...d2d1d0' where di = the i'th digit.

Number = ... d2 * N^2 + d1 * N^1 + d0 * N^0

Then just add the numbers as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Idea: it looks like hashing, but in hash function you can't use negative numbers.